# Passing numpy arrays from python to javascript

Tags: python, node.js, numpy

I have a written a source program in python that calculates and returns a numpy array of 3 numbers. Now ,i am trying to pass this array to a javascript front end program to display.
So far , i have tried using a child process in js invoking the python program, but i am stuck in the array transfer part. 
I have also looked at python-shell npm package , but have no idea how to work with it.
How do i proceed? 
Is it better if i convert the array to a json file and send the json to the js program?

Comment: is the python program a web server? if so send the python array as a json to frontend javasctipt app

Comment: Convert the array to a list and then a JSON string.

Answer (score 2):

Python has a module to encode objects as JSON strings:

```
import json

In [54]: json.dumps(np.arange(10).tolist())
Out[54]: '[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]'
```

Arrays in Javascript are similar to Python lists.  `numpy` arrays add level of complexity that you don't need, especially with only 3 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have 3 numbers, then you might as well use JSON. But if you have 300,000 then you should consider transferring them as compressed binary (e.g. zlib).

For example, if you are using Flask then

```
        s = pickle.dumps(data, protocol=3)
        e = zlib.compress(s)
        r = make_response(e)
        setattr(r,"mimetype", "application/octet-stream")
```

Then on the javascript side you need to unpack what you get from Ajax with

```
    const encoded_data = pako.inflate(binary_array)   
    const gxl = mpickle.loads(encoded_data.buffer)
```

Details are here:

[Is there an already published Javascript solution to traverse Python pickled objects without using Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71797909/is-there-an-already-published-javascript-solution-to-traverse-python-pickled-obj)