# Is there an already published Javascript solution to traverse Python pickled objects without using Node.js

Tags: javascript, python, blob, pickle, arraybuffer

I'm looking at https://github.com/jlaine/node-jpickle to traverse through pickle objects in Javascript and that would be useful to assist sending binary objects from Python, through Ajax, to Javascript. Unfortunately, it uses Node.js to traverse something called Buffer() whereas I get an ArrayBuffer from the Ajax blob. No problem, a few places on the internet have the code below and it should be simple to modify jpickle to use this:

```
var ArrayBufferCursor = function() {
  var ArrayBufferCursor = function(arrayBuffer) {
    this.dataview = new DataView(arrayBuffer, 0);
    this.size = arrayBuffer.byteLength;
    this.index = 0;
  }

  ArrayBufferCursor.prototype.next = function(type) {
    switch(type) {
      case 'Uint8':
        var result = this.dataview.getUint8(this.index);
        this.index += 1;
        return result;
      case 'Int16':
        var result = this.dataview.getInt16(this.index, true);
        this.index += 2;
        return result;
      case 'Uint16':
        var result = this.dataview.getUint16(this.index, true);
        this.index += 2;
        return result;
      case 'Int32':
        var result = this.dataview.getInt32(this.index, true);
        this.index += 4;
        return result;
      case 'Uint32':
        var result = this.dataview.getUint32(this.index, true);
        this.index += 4;
        return result;
      case 'Float':
      case 'Float32':
        var result = this.dataview.getFloat32(this.index, true);
        this.index += 4;
        return result;
      case 'Double':
      case 'Float64':
        var result = this.dataview.getFloat64(this.index, true);
        this.index += 8;
        return result;
      default:
        throw new Error("Unknown datatype");
    }
  };

  ArrayBufferCursor.prototype.hasNext = function() {
    return this.index < this.size;
  }

  return ArrayBufferCursor;
});
```

Except this code has at least one typo. For example, maybe I should delete that very last parenthesis? If I do so, then Chrome browser happily compiles, which should allow me to do:

```
var cursor = new ArrayBufferCursor(arrayBuffer);
firstfloat = cursor.next('Float')
```

Except Chrome complains that `cursor.next` is not a function. Grrr. I suspect a trivial typo in this code is stopping it from working, but I cant work it out. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: The title asks for a library -> off-topic. The body then talks about something unrelated to `pickle` and an error to then end in an (slightly off-topic) _"Any idea?"_ followed by an off-topic _"search this for me on SO"_.

Comment: Fair enough. How about "Is there an already published Javascript solution to traverse Python pickled objects without using Node.js ?"

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be good now. Apart from fixing the confusing brackets, to work with pickle you have to set floating point numbers to BigEndian, not Little, which fooled me for a while.

These cursor functions now let you iterate through a Pickle object !!

```
let ArrayBufferCursor = function(arrayBuffer) {
    this.dataview = new DataView(arrayBuffer, 0);
    this.size = arrayBuffer.byteLength;
    this.index = 0;
  }

ArrayBufferCursor.prototype.next = function(type) {
    switch(type) {
      case 'Char8':
        var result = String.fromCharCode(this.dataview.getUint8(this.index));
        this.index += 1;
        return result;
      case 'Uint8':
        var result = this.dataview.getUint8(this.index);
        this.index += 1;
        return result;
      case 'Int16':
        var result = this.dataview.getInt16(this.index, true);
        this.index += 2;
        return result;
      case 'Uint16':
        var result = this.dataview.getUint16(this.index, true);
        this.index += 2;
        return result;
      case 'Int32':
        var result = this.dataview.getInt32(this.index, true);
        this.index += 4;
        return result;
      case 'Uint32':
        var result = this.dataview.getUint32(this.index, true);
        this.index += 4;
        return result;
      case 'Float':
      case 'Float32':
        var result = this.dataview.getFloat32(this.index, false);
        this.index += 4;
        return result;
      case 'Double':
      case 'Float64':
        var result = this.dataview.getFloat64(this.index, false);
        this.index += 8;
        return result;
      default:
        throw new Error("Unknown datatype");
    }
  };

ArrayBufferCursor.prototype.toString = function(n) {
    const slice = new Uint8Array(this.dataview.buffer).subarray(this.index,this.index+n); //from current pointer get the next n bytes                                  //convert to uint8
    const bytesString = String.fromCharCode(...slice)                                           //and then string
    this.index += n;
    return bytesString;
  }

ArrayBufferCursor.prototype.readLine = function() {
    const slice = new Uint8Array(this.dataview.buffer).subarray(this.index)      // is this a data copy or just a pointer? The former could get expensive...
    const n = this.size - this.index - 1                     // is it really "-1" hope so. Anyway, the very last byte wont be a '\n' will it??

    let i = 0
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++) {
       if (slice[i] == 10){                                 //i.e. ascii '\n'
          break;}
    }

    if (i == n) {
        throw "Could not find end of a line in pickle?!";
    }
    const bytesArray = new Uint8Array(this.dataview.buffer).subarray(this.index, this.index+i);
    const bytesString = String.fromCharCode(...bytesArray);
    this.index += i+1;                                 // throw away the '\n'
    return bytesString;
  }

ArrayBufferCursor.prototype.hasNext = function() {
    return this.index < this.size;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

And in case unclear the rest of the solution is basically copied from the previously published Node.js. But the result is very nice. Pickle->Zlib on the python side then Pako->Jpickle on the Javascript side gives a complete mechanism to transfer Python objects via Ajax without needing to go to Json and strings. Work to be done includes adding a 'fake' emulator for numpy arrays....

```
var Parser = function() {
    this.mark = 'THIS-NEEDS-TO-BE-UNIQUE-TO-SERVE-AS-A-BOUNDARY';
    this.memo = {};
    this.stack = [];
};

Parser.prototype.load = function(pickle) {                                // pickle is an ArrayBuffer
    var MARK = '('              // push special markobject on stack
      , STOP = '.'              // every pickle ends with STOP
      , POP = '0'               // discard topmost stack item
      , POP_MARK = '1'          // discard stack top through topmost markobject
      , DUP = '2'               // duplicate top stack item
      , FLOAT = 'F'             // push float object; decimal string argument
      , INT = 'I'               // push integer or bool; decimal string argument
      , BININT = 'J'            // push 4-byte signed int
      , BININT1 = 'K'           // push 1-byte unsigned int
      , LONG = 'L'              // push long; decimal string argument
      , BININT2 = 'M'           // push 2-byte unsigned int
      , NONE = 'N'              // push None
      // missing PERSID
      // missing BINPERSID
      , REDUCE = 'R'            // apply callable to argtuple, both on stack
      , STRING = 'S'            // push string; NL-terminated string argument
      , BINSTRING = 'T'         // push string; counted binary string argument
      , SHORT_BINSTRING = 'U'   //  "     "   ;    "      "       "      " < 256 bytes
      , UNICODE = 'V'           // push Unicode string; raw-unicode-escaped'd argument
      , BINUNICODE = 'X'        //   "     "       "  ; counted UTF-8 string argument
      , APPEND = 'a'            // append stack top to list below it
      , BUILD = 'b'             // build the entire value
      , GLOBAL = 'c'            // push self.find_class(modname, name); 2 string args
      , DICT = 'd'              // build a dict from stack items
      , EMPTY_DICT = '}'        // push empty dict
      , APPENDS = 'e'           // extend list on stack by topmost stack slice
      , GET = 'g'               // push item from memo on stack; index is string arg
      , BINGET = 'h'            //   "    "    "    "   "   "  ;   "    " 1-byte arg
      // missing INST
      , LONG_BINGET = 'j'       // push item from memo on stack; index is 4-byte arg
      , LIST = 'l'              // build list from topmost stack items
      , EMPTY_LIST = ']'        // push empty list
      , OBJ = 'o'               // build a class instance using the objects between here and the mark
      , PUT = 'p'               // store stack top in memo; index is string arg
      , BINPUT = 'q'            //   "     "    "   "   " ;   "    " 1-byte arg
      , LONG_BINPUT = 'r'       //   "     "    "   "   " ;   "    " 4-byte arg
      , SETITEM = 's'           // add key+value pair to dict
      , TUPLE = 't'             // build tuple from topmost stack items
      , EMPTY_TUPLE = ')'       // push empty tuple
      , SETITEMS = 'u'          // modify dict by adding topmost key+value pairs
      , BINFLOAT = 'G'          // push float; arg is 8-byte float encoding
      // protocol 2
      , PROTO = '\x80'          // identify pickle protocol
      , NEWOBJ = '\x81'         // build object by applying cls.__new__ to argtuple
      , TUPLE1 = '\x85'         // build 1-tuple from stack top
      , TUPLE2 = '\x86'         // build 2-tuple from two topmost stack items
      , TUPLE3 = '\x87'         // build 3-tuple from three topmost stack items
      , NEWTRUE = '\x88'        // push True
      , NEWFALSE = '\x89'       // push False
      , LONG1 = '\x8a'          // push long from < 256 bytes
      , LONG4 = '\x8b'          // push really big long
      // protocol 3
      , BINBYTES = 'B'          // push bytes; counted binary string argument
      , SHORT_BINBYTES = 'C'    //  "     "   ;    "      "       "      " < 256 bytes
      ;

    var cursor = new ArrayBufferCursor(pickle)

    let i = 0;
    let opcode = 0;
    for (;cursor.hasNext();) {
        opcode = cursor.next('Char8');
        switch (opcode) {
        // protocol 2
        case PROTO:
            var proto = cursor.next('Uint8');
            if (proto !== 2 && proto !== 3)
                throw 'Unhandled pickle protocol version: ' + proto;
            break;
        case TUPLE1:
            var a = this.stack.pop();
            this.stack.push([a]);
            break;
        case TUPLE2:
            var b = this.stack.pop()
              , a = this.stack.pop();
            this.stack.push([a, b]);
            break;
        case TUPLE3:
            var c = this.stack.pop()
              , b = this.stack.pop()
              , a = this.stack.pop();
            this.stack.push([a, b, c]);
            break;
        case NEWTRUE:
            this.stack.push(true);
            break;
        case NEWFALSE:
            this.stack.push(false);
            break;
        case LONG1:
            var length = cursor.next('Uint8'); 
            this.stack.push(0);
            break;
        case LONG4:   // UNTESTED, might be broken
            var length = cursor.next('Uint32'); 
            this.stack.push(0);
            break; 
        case POP:
            this.stack.pop();
            break;
        case POP_MARK:
            var mark = this.marker();
            this.stack = this.stack.slice(0, mark);
            break;
        case DUP:
            var value = this.stack[this.stack.length-1];
            this.stack.push(value);
            break;
        case EMPTY_DICT:
            this.stack.push({});
            break;
        case EMPTY_LIST:
        case EMPTY_TUPLE:
            this.stack.push([]);
            break;
        case GET:
            var index = cursor.readLine(); 
            this.stack.push(this.memo[index]);
            break;
        case BINGET:
            var index = cursor.next('Uint8');
            this.stack.push(this.memo[''+index]);
            break;
        case LONG_BINGET:
            var index = cursor.next('Uint32'); 
            this.stack.push(this.memo[''+index]);
            break;
        case PUT:
            var index = cursor.readLine(); 
            this.memo[index] = this.stack[this.stack.length-1];
            break;
        case BINPUT:
            var index = cursor.next('Uint8');;
            this.memo['' + index] = this.stack[this.stack.length-1];
            break;
        case LONG_BINPUT:
            var index = cursor.next('Uint32'); 
            this.memo['' + index] = this.stack[this.stack.length-1];
            break;
        case GLOBAL:
            var module = cursor.readLine(); 
            var name = cursor.readLine(); 
            var func = emulated[module + '.' + name];           //if it is a class then emulated must be called first
            if (func === undefined) {
                throw "Cannot emulate global: " + module + " " + name;
            }
            this.stack.push(func);
            break;
        case OBJ:
            var obj = new (this.stack.pop())();
            var mark = this.marker();
            for (var pos = mark + 1; pos < this.stack.length; pos += 2) {
              obj[this.stack[pos]] = this.stack[pos + 1];
            }
            this.stack = this.stack.slice(0, mark);
            this.stack.push(obj);
            break;
        case BUILD:
            var dict = this.stack.pop();
            var obj = this.stack.pop();
            for ( var p in dict ) {
              obj[p] = dict[p];
            }
            this.stack.push(obj);
            break;
        case REDUCE:
            var args = this.stack.pop();
            var func = this.stack[this.stack.length - 1];
            this.stack[this.stack.length - 1] = func(args);
            break;
        case INT:
            var value = cursor.readLine(); 
            if (value == '01')
                this.stack.push(true);
            else if (value == '00')
                this.stack.push(false);
            else
                this.stack.push(parseInt(value));
            break;
        case BININT:
            this.stack.push(cursor.next('Uint32'));
            i += 4;
            break;
        case BININT1:
            this.stack.push(cursor.next('Uint8'));
            i += 1;
            break;
        case BININT2:
            this.stack.push(cursor.next('Uint16'));
            i += 2;
            break;
        case MARK:
            this.stack.push(this.mark);
            break;
        case FLOAT:
            var value = cursor.readLine();
            i += value.length + 1;
            this.stack.push(parseFloat(value));
            break;
        case LONG:
            var value = cursor.readLine();
            i += value.length + 1;
            this.stack.push(parseInt(value));
            break;
        case BINFLOAT:
            this.stack.push(cursor.next('Float64'));
            i += 8;
            break;
        case STRING:
            var value = cursor.readLine();
            i += value.length + 1;
            var quotes = "\"'";
            if (value[0] == "'") {
                if (value[value.length-1] != "'")
                    throw "insecure string pickle";
            } else if (value[0] = '"') {
                if (value[value.length-1] != '"')
                    throw "insecure string pickle";
            } else {
                throw "insecure string pickle";
            }
            this.stack.push(value.substr(1, value.length-2));
            break;
        case UNICODE:
            var value = cursor.readLine();
            i += value.length + 1;
            this.stack.push(value);
            break;
        case BINSTRING:
        case BINBYTES:
            var length = cursor.next('Uint32');
            i += 4;
            this.stack.push(cursor.toString(length));
            i += length;
            break;
        case SHORT_BINSTRING:
        case SHORT_BINBYTES:
            var length = cursor.next('Uint8');
            this.stack.push(cursor.toString(length));
            i += length;
            break;
        case BINUNICODE:
            var length = cursor.next('Uint32');
            i += 4;
            this.stack.push(cursor.toString(length));
            i += length;
            break;
        case APPEND:
            var value = this.stack.pop();
            this.stack[this.stack.length-1].push(value);
            break;
        case APPENDS:
            var mark = this.marker(),
                list = this.stack[mark - 1];
            list.push.apply(list, this.stack.slice(mark + 1));
            this.stack = this.stack.slice(0, mark);
            break;
        case SETITEM:
            var value = this.stack.pop()
              , key = this.stack.pop();
            this.stack[this.stack.length-1][key] = value;
            break;
        case SETITEMS:
            var mark = this.marker()
              , obj = this.stack[mark - 1];
            for (var pos = mark + 1; pos < this.stack.length; pos += 2) {
                obj[this.stack[pos]] = this.stack[pos + 1];
            }
            this.stack = this.stack.slice(0, mark);
            break;
        case LIST:
        case TUPLE:
            var mark = this.marker()
              , list = this.stack.slice(mark + 1);
            this.stack = this.stack.slice(0, mark);
            this.stack.push(list);
            break;
        case DICT:
            var mark = this.marker()
                obj = {};
            for (var pos = mark + 1; pos < this.stack.length; pos += 2) {
                obj[this.stack[pos]] = this.stack[pos + 1];
            }
            this.stack = this.stack.slice(0, mark);
            this.stack.push(obj);
            break;
        case STOP:
            return this.stack.pop();
        case NONE:
            this.stack.push(null);
            break;
        default: 
            throw "Unhandled opcode " + opcode + " " + String.fromCharCode(opcode) ;
        }
    }
};

Parser.prototype.marker = function(parser) {
    var k = this.stack.length - 1
    while (k > 0 && this.stack[k] !== this.mark) {
        --k;
    }
    return k;
};
```

T.